# Generating not fully filled array with C

Tags: arrays, c

Is it possible to generate an array of 5 elements, which can be not filled in full?

The array I want to create can have a maximum size of 5 elements, as shown in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 5
void sort (int *, int);
void create (int *tab, int size);
void display();
void insert();
void del();
void exit();


int main()
{
    int c;
    int arr[M];
    printf("Choose an option: \n");
    printf("1. Input values to the array (MUST BE DONE FIRST).\n");
    printf("2. Show elements of the array.\n");
    printf("3. Update array.\n");
    printf("4. Remove element from the array.\n");
    printf("5. Sort array. \n");
    printf("6. Exit program.\n");
    printf("\nYour option: ");
    scanf("%d", c);
    
    switch(c)
    {
        case 1:
        create(arr, size);
        break;
        
        case 2:
        display();
        break;
        
        case 3:
        insert();
        break;
        
        case 4:
        del();
        break;
        
        case 5:
        sort(int *, int);
        break;
        
        case 6:
        exit();
        break;
    }
}

void create(int *tab, int size)
{
    printf("Input amount of elements in array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
}
```

That's what I've done so far. In the previous version of the code, instead of filling only several elements from all 5, program filled a whole array, putting random values in cells higher than amount of input elements (e.g. in an array which had to have only three elements filled, it was filled fully, except `arr[3]` and `arr[4]` were displaying unwanted values:

```
 ******** MAIN MENU *********
 1. Create table (CREATE IT FIRST!!!!) 
 2. Display table
 3. Add element
 4. Delete element
 5. EXIT
 Enter your option : 1

Input amount of elements: 3

 ******** MAIN MENU *********
 1. Create table (CREATE IT FIRST!!!!) 
 2. Display table
 3. Add element
 4. Delete element
 5. EXIT
 Enter your option : 3
Tab[0]: 1
Tab[1]: 2
Tab[2]: 3
Tab[3]: 4
Tab[4]: 5
Tab[5]: 6
Tab[6]: 7
Tab[7]: 8

 ******** MAIN MENU *********
 1. Create table (CREATE IT FIRST!!!!) 
 2. Display table
 3. Add element
 4. Delete element
 5. EXIT
 Enter your option : 2
1 2 3 4 5 
 ******** MAIN MENU *********
 1. Create table (CREATE IT FIRST!!!!) 
 2. Display table
 3. Add element
 4. Delete element
 5. EXIT
 Enter your option :
```

So, is it possible to generate a not fully filled array in C?

Comment: *You* control the number of elements in the array that are considered to be valid. Maintain a count independent of the length of the allocated array.

Comment: The C language has no concept of "empty". You declare a variable or array, and it allocates memory for it, and it contains whatever is in that memory. If you want to create an array with "empty" elements, you have to do that yourself by using other variables to keep track of what's used and not used.

Comment: To be a bit more precise, for an automatic ("stack-allocated") fixed-size array, you can choose to leave it uninitialised or you can initialise to a compile-time list of values. If you choose to initialise it, you don't have to provide a complete list; the rest of the array will be initialised to 0. If you don't initialise it, it's undefined behaviour to use any element from the array before it has been assigned to. In this particular case, I'd suggest using dynamic allocation, not automatic allocation.

Comment: There is something off here. Why are you entering 8 values to a 5-element array? And `scanf("%d", c);` would not have worked anyway - `scanf("%d", &c);`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can initialize partially an array, but the full array will be filled.  The non initialized elements will be zeroed.